# Java serialization bug when facing circular dependency with a Set

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

My project is a `java` project over `EJB3` using Hibernate and `Weblogic` server.

For convenience sake (and as far as I understand, is typical to `hibernate`), some of the entities contains circular dependency (Parent knows the child, child know the parent). Further, for some of the child classes - the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method depend on their parent (As it is a unique key).

When working I saw an odd behavior - Some of the Sets that returned from the server to the client, although containing the right elements, acted like they contained none. For example, a simple test such as this: `set.contains(set.toArray()[0])` returned `false` although the `hashCode()` method is a good one.

After extensive debugging I was able to produce 2 simple classes that reproduce the problem (I can assure you the `hashCode()` function in both classes is **reflexive, transitive and symmetrical**):

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class ClientTest implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SerializableClass serializationTest = new SerializableClass();
        FieldOfSerializableClass hashMember = new FieldOfSerializableClass();
        hashMember.setParentLink(serializationTest);
        serializationTest.setHashCodeField("Some string");
        serializationTest
                .setSomeSet(new HashSet<FieldOfSerializableClass>());
        serializationTest.getSomeSet().add(hashMember);
        System.out.println("Does it contain its member? (should return true!) "
                + serializationTest.getSomeSet().contains(hashMember));
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("temp"))
                .writeObject(serializationTest);
        SerializableClass testAfterDeserialize = (SerializableClass) new ObjectInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(new File("temp"))).readObject();
        System.out.println("Does it contain its member? (should return true!) "
                + testAfterDeserialize.getSomeSet().contains(hashMember));

        for (Object o : testAfterDeserialize.getSomeSet()) {
            System.out.println("Does it contain its member by equality? (should return true!) "+ o.equals(hashMember));
        }

    }

    public static class SerializableClass implements Serializable {
        private Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> mSomeSet;
        private String mHashCodeField;

        public void setSomeSet(Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> pSomeSet) {
            mSomeSet = pSomeSet;
        }

        public Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> getSomeSet() {
            return mSomeSet;
        }

        public void setHashCodeField(String pHashCodeField) {
            mHashCodeField = pHashCodeField;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;

            System.out.println("In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: "
                    + mHashCodeField);
            result = prime
                    * result
                    + ((mHashCodeField == null) ? 0 : mHashCodeField.hashCode());
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            SerializableClass other = (SerializableClass) obj;

            if (mHashCodeField == null) {
                if (other.mHashCodeField != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!mHashCodeField.equals(other.mHashCodeField))
                return false;
            return true;
        }

        private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            System.out.println("Just started serializing");
            in.defaultReadObject();
            System.out.println("Just finished serializing");
        }
    }

    public static class FieldOfSerializableClass implements Serializable {
        private SerializableClass mParentLink;

        public void setParentLink(SerializableClass pParentLink) {
            mParentLink = pParentLink;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result
                    + ((mParentLink == null) ? 0 : mParentLink.hashCode());

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            FieldOfSerializableClass other = (FieldOfSerializableClass) obj;
            if (mParentLink == null) {
                if (other.mParentLink != null) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (!mParentLink.equals(other.mParentLink))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

This produced the following output:

```
    In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: Some string
    In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: Some string
    Does it contain its member? (should return true!) true
    Just started serializing
    In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: null
    Just finished serializing
    In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: Some string
    Does it contain its member? (should return true!) false
    Does it contain its member by equality? (should return true!) true
```

This tells me that the order in which Java serializes the object is wrong! It starts serializing the Set before the String, and thus causing the above problem.

What should I do in this situation? Is there any option (aside from implementing `readResolve` for many entities...) to direct java to serialize a class in a certain order?
Also, is it fundamentally wrong for an entity to base its `hashCode` on its parent?

**Edit**: A solution was suggested by a colleague - Because I'm using Hibernate, every entity has a unique long ID. I know that Hibernate specify not to use this ID in the equals method - but what about hashCode? Using this unique ID as hashcode seems to solve the above problem with a minimal risk of performance issues. Are there any other implications to using the ID as hashcode?

**SECOND EDIT**: I went and implemented my partial solution (All of the enteties now use the ID field for the hashCode() function and no longer relay on other enteties for it) but, alas, Serialization bugs still continue to plague me! Below is a sample code with another serialization bug. What I think is happening is this - ClassA start deserializing, sees it has a ClassB to deserialize and BEFORE it deserializes its ID, it start deserializing the ClassB. B start to deserialize and Sees it has a Set of ClassA. The ClassA instance is partialy deserialized, but even though ClassB adds it to the Set (using the missing ID of ClassA), completes the deserializning, ClassA then completes and the bug occurs.

What can I do to solve this?! Circular dependencies is a very used practice in Hibernate and I just can't accept it that i'm the only one with this problem.

Another possible solution is to have a dedicated variable for the hashCode (will be calculated by the object's ID) and make sure (view readObject and writeObject) that it will be read BEFORE VERY OTHER OBJECT. What do you think? Are there any disadvantages to this solution?

The sample code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test implements Serializable
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        ClassA aClass = new ClassA();
        aClass.setId(Long.valueOf(321));

        ClassB bClass = new ClassB();
        bClass.setId(Long.valueOf(921));

        Set<ClassA> set = new HashSet<ClassA>();
        set.add(aClass);

        bClass.setSetfield(set);
        aClass.setBField(bClass);

        Set<ClassA> goodClassA = aClass.getBField().getSetfield();
        Set<ClassA> badClassA = serializeAndDeserialize(aClass).getBField().getSetfield();

        System.out.println("Does it contain its member? (should return true!) " + goodClassA.contains(goodClassA.toArray()[0]));
        System.out.println("Does it contain its member? (should return true!) " + badClassA.contains(badClassA.toArray()[0]));
    }

    public static ClassA serializeAndDeserialize(ClassA s) throws Exception
    {
        new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("temp"))).writeObject(s);
        return (ClassA) new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File("temp"))).readObject();
    }

    public static class ClassB implements Serializable
    {
        private Long mId;
        private Set<ClassA> mSetfield = new HashSet<ClassA>();
        public Long getmId() {
            return mId;
        }
        public void setId(Long mId) {
            this.mId = mId;
        }
        public Set<ClassA> getSetfield() {
            return mSetfield;
        }
        public void setSetfield(Set<ClassA> mSetfield) {
            this.mSetfield = mSetfield;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((mId == null) ? 0 : mId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ClassB other = (ClassB) obj;
            if (mId == null) {
                if (other.mId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!mId.equals(other.mId))
                return false;
            return true;
        }       
    }

    public static class ClassA implements Serializable
    {
        private Long mId;
        private ClassB mBField;
        public Long getmId() {
            return mId;
        }
        public void setId(Long mId) {
            this.mId = mId;
        }
        public ClassB getBField() {
            return mBField;
        }
        public void setBField(ClassB mBField) {
            this.mBField = mBField;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 1;
            result = prime * result + ((mId == null) ? 0 : mId.hashCode());
            return result;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ClassA other = (ClassA) obj;
            if (mId == null) {
                if (other.mId != null)
                    return false;
            } else if (!mId.equals(other.mId))
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you use a `LinkedHashSet`?

Comment: Please fix the typos. The code does not compile.

Comment: Fixing the typos is quite hard since The computer on which I wrote the code is not connected to the internet... I will do what I can though.

Comment: I fixed the typos and added one check in the code, thus I also added one line to the original output...

Answer (score 1):

So as I read it, you are basing the hashCode of `FieldOfSerializableClass` on the parent object.  This seems to be the ultimate cause of your problem and a very questionable design.  `hashCode()` and `equals()` method deal with object identity and should not at all be related to what parent contains them.  The idea that the identity of an object changes depending on which parent object owns it is very foreign to me at least and is the ultimate reason why your code doesn't work.

Although the other answers have some ways to work around the problem, I think the easiest way to fix this is to give the `FieldOfSerializableClass` class its own identity.  You could copy the `mHashCodeField` from the `SerializableClass` to the `FieldOfSerializableClass`.  When the parent is set on the object you can take its `mHashCodeField` and store it locally.

```
public void setParentLink(SerializableClass pParentLink) {
    this.mHashCodeField = pParentLink.mHashCodeField;
    mParentLink = pParentLink;
}
```

Then the hashcode (and equals) method looks similar to the one for `SerializableClass`.

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return ((mHashCodeField == null) ? 0 : mHashCodeField.hashCode());
}
```

But really you should consider changing the code so the parental relationship is less coupled.  Consider for a second what happens if you call `setParentLink()` on a field while it is already in another `SerializableClass` set.  All of a sudden the original class can't even find the item in its set since its identity has changed.  Assigning some sort identity to the `FieldOfSerializableClass` class that is unique from the parent class is the best pattern here in terms of Java objects.

You could use `UUID.randomUUID()` or some static `AtomicInteger` on the class that give a new id each time if you can't use the other fields in `FieldOfSerializableClass` as a proper identity.  But I'd use the auto-generated id given to you from Hibernate.  You just need to make sure that the object has been inserted into the database *before* it gets put in another object's collection.

Comment: I am aware that coupling objects is not a good practice (to say the least!) but the above situation is the one that correctly represents the DB. Consider a Course and a Professor. The same course (For example "Advanced Java") can be taught simultaneously during the semester with different teachers. The teacher is a vital key of the course (Say, teacher key and course name). Of course, I can assign the course a unique ID (and I do), but as previously mentioned, it's not a good practice in hibernate.

Comment: The Professor may be "vital" to the Course but that shouldn't impact the Course's identity.  Professor Smith may be teaching the Friday Advanced Java course which people sign up for.  If he switches to the one on Tuesday then the people who signed up don't get immediately moved to Tuesday.  That the Professor changes shouldn't effect the class.  But really, this is a metaphor and what we are talking about is Java design patterns.  Identities should _not_ be affected by object ownership.

Comment: In terms of hibernate not wanting to use the identity as the hashcode, this only applies if the object has not been inserted into the database.  You create the Course in the database before you can add it to the Professor's collection.  I don't see a problem.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en-US/html/persistent-classes.html#persistent-classes-equalshashcode

Answer (score 0):

It is the equals method that has to be reflexive, transitive and symmetrical...

The hashCode method must have [these properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29):

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
>
> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
>
> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hashtables.

Here, it looks like the hashCode used to put the entry in the set during deserialization is different from the one calculated during the contains(). BTW as you noticed the entry *is* in the Set you just cannot access it through it's hashCode, if you loop over the content of the Set you will find the elements.

Possible solutions:

- have a hashCode not relying on the parent object.
- use a datastructure that is not using hashcode (List, TreeSet...)
- do not use the contains method on the Set...
- implement ReadResolve to recreate the Set after desirialization...

**[EDIT]:** It looks like you are not alone [bug_id=4957674](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4957674)

Comment: My hashcode has this properties (plus its reflexive, etc.). The problem occurs only DURING SERILIZATION as mHashCodeField is not serilized in the correct order (AFTER serialization the hashcode is fine).

Comment: In fact the log you write in the readObject method is written during deserialization, not during serialization...

Comment: Yes, of course, I got confused a bit, but the meaning is the same - the problem with the hashcode occurs on a very specific time in the application. Otherwise, from every other aspect it is written just fine.

Comment: Regarding your edit - It is good to know I'm not alone :) I havn't seen any good workarounds there except (Maybe) one - Changing the readResolve of hashmap so it won't recompute the hashCode of objects at serializtion, instead keep the hashCode values of before, which raises the question - Why does HashMap recompute the map at deserializtion?

Answer (score 0):

Deserailization reads values of both fields (`mHashCodeField` and `mSomeSet`) into temporary array and after both values are deserialized it sets the fields to the stored values.

Since HashSet recalculates hash codes of its elements during deserialization it will use `mHashCodeField` when it is still null.

Possible solution is to mark `mSomeSet` as transient and write/read it in writeObject/readObject.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println("Just started deserializing");
    in.defaultReadObject();
    mSomeSet=(Set<FieldOfSerializableClass>)in.readObject();
    System.out.println("Just finished deserializing");        
}
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("Just started serializing");
    out.defaultWriteObject();
    out.writeObject(mSomeSet);
    System.out.println("Just finished serializing");        
}
```

Comment: Marking mHashCodeField as transient won't iterfere with hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Hibernate says not to use the id as hashcode, but I believe they're being too strict about it. This makes sense only if the id is autogenerated/autoincremented by Hibernate. In this case, you might have a bean that receives its id value only when Hibernate decides to actually persist it to the database, so in this situation you might get unpredictable behaviour from a hashcode and/or equals method that uses the id. However if the id is manually set, i.e. your application deals with populating this value then I believe it's perfectly ok to use it in your hashcode/equals methods. Is this the case for you?

Comment: In my case the ID is autogenerated and incremented by the DB I belive. Now - does hibernate forbid using ID in **hashcode** or **equals**? What I want is to use the ID for the hashcode only - The equals will still work with the unique ID. Will there be a problem with such a setup?

Comment: It's not forbidden per se, Hibernate just "frawns upon" it. Article here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode, maybe it will help you decide.

Comment: I've read the article - It seems to me that indeed using the ID is troublesome only when used in equals(). hashCode() is used to determine to which bucket an entry will be inserted. Even if all my objects used '0' as their hashCode, the worst that will happen will be a performance degradation in Hashtables, but the object will be retrieved correctly all the same. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yep that's theoretically true, with the duly necessary observation that if you have your hashcode implemented such that it returns 0 for any instance, when using a hastable-like collection you'll get the performance of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

I add another answer because it's very different from my first one:

Here is an implementation that works without a transient field, I found the necessary information here: [Advanced Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/serialization/) and [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=403c14cade486ffffffffb4d17aff6051318?bug_id=6208166).

By the way I also tried to use the `serialPersistentFields` attribute to force that mHashCodeFields gets serialized first but it didn't help...

```
    public static class SerializableClass implements Serializable {
    
    // this tells the serialization mechanism to serialize only mHasCodeField...
    private final static ObjectStreamField[]
            serialPersistentFields = {
              new ObjectStreamField(
              "mHashCodeField", String.class)
            };

    
    private String mHashCodeField;
    private Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> mSomeSet;
    

    public void setSomeSet(Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> pSomeSet) {
        mSomeSet = pSomeSet;
    }

    public Set<FieldOfSerializableClass> getSomeSet() {
        return mSomeSet;
    }

    public void setHashCodeField(String pHashCodeField) {
        mHashCodeField = pHashCodeField;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;

        System.out.println("In hashCode - value of mHashCodeField: "
                + mHashCodeField);
        
        result = prime
                * result
                + ((mHashCodeField == null) ? 0 : mHashCodeField.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SerializableClass other = (SerializableClass) obj;

        if (mHashCodeField == null) {
            if (other.mHashCodeField != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!mHashCodeField.equals(other.mHashCodeField))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Just started serializing");
        out.defaultWriteObject();
        out.writeObject(mSomeSet);


        System.out.println("In writeObject - value of mHashCodeField: "
                + mHashCodeField);
        System.out.println("Just finished serializing");
    }

    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Just started deserializing");
        in.defaultReadObject();
        mSomeSet=(Set<FieldOfSerializableClass>)in.readObject();

        System.out.println("In readObject - value of mHashCodeField: "
                + mHashCodeField);
        System.out.println("Just finished deserializing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to generify this solution? It will be too comlex and time consuming to implement this to all the problematic entities.

Comment: Using a List instead of a Set is not an option?

Comment: I have considered it, and it may be applicable to most of the cases, but HashMap (and not set) IS vital in some of the entities.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me this is a bug in java, not your sourcecode.  While the answers above give good workaround options, the best solution would be for Java to fix how deserialization works to account for circular references and sets/hashmaps.

See here for making a new bug report:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/

The more people who report this bug, the greater chance they will fix it.  I too am getting this error in my project, and the work-arounds are far more effort than they are worth to me.

Also, here is a similar bug report I found:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=fb27da16bb769ffffffffebce29d31b2574e?bug_id=6208166

Comment: I don't think they will ever fix it - in fact, Josh Bloch gave this bug as a puzzle in his book Java Puzzels (P91) where he stated that this will probably won't ever be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. I think you're right in your second edit about the cause. Here is my simplest replication of the issue:

```
public class Test {

    static class Thing implements Serializable {
        String name;
        Set<Thing> others = new HashSet<Thing>();

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            if (name == null) {
                System.out.println("hashcode called with null name!");
            }
            return name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return o instanceof Thing && ((Thing) o).name == name;
        }
    }

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testHashSetCircularDependencySerialization() throws Exception {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        thing.name = "thing";
        Thing thing2 = new Thing();
        thing2.name = "thing2";
        thing.others.add(thing2);
        thing2.others.add(thing);
        assertTrue(thing2.others.contains(thing));
        Thing thingCopy = (Thing) serializeAndDeserialize(thing);
        Thing thing2Copy = thingCopy.others.iterator().next();
        assertTrue(thing2Copy.others.contains(thingCopy));
    }

    public static Object serializeAndDeserialize(Object other) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        new ObjectOutputStream(byteOutputStream).writeObject(other);
        ByteArrayInputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutputStream.toByteArray());
        return new ObjectInputStream(byteInputStream).readObject();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
hashcode called with null name!
```

This test fails. The simplest solution I found was to keep a copy of the hashcode. Because it's a primative, it gets set when the object is initialized during deserialization, not later:

```
    int hashcode;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        if (hashcode != 0) {
            return hashcode;
        }
        hashcode = name == null ? 0 : name.hashCode();
        return hashcode;
    }
```

The test now passes.

Answer (score 0):

[JDK-4957674 : (coll) Hash entries placed into wrong buckets during deserialization](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4957674)

> When deserializing a HashMap, the readObject() method reads the key-value pairs and re-hashes the map by calling hashCode() on the keys.
>
> But if the keys' implementation of hashCode() depends on some internal variable of the key, and if that variable has not yet been deserialized at that moment, then hashCode() will give the wrong result, sending the key into the wrong hash bucket.

**Workaround:**

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    ...
    out.writeObject(new ArrayList<>(theSet));
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ...
    theSet = new HashSet<>((ArrayList) in.readObject());
}
```