# Serializing HashMap with a custom serialized object

Tags: java, serialization, java-8

I declare the HashMap, inside the ActionHandler class:

```
public class ActionHandler {
    private HashMap<Cooldown, Long> cooldowns = new HashMap<Cooldown, Long>();

    public void disInit(Main main) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        String path = main.getDataFolder() + File.separator + "cooldowns.dat";
        File serialize = new File(path);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serialize));
        oos.writeObject(cooldowns);
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        serialize.createNewFile();
    }
}
```

```
public class Cooldown implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2233153996259053084L;
    private String username;
    private Shop shop;
    public Cooldown(String username, Shop shop){
        //constructing setting the fields...
    }
    public String getUsername(){//returning the fields
    public Shop getShop(){//return shop;}
}
```

The console spits out this error whenever the plugin serializes the file (with disInit). I am stoked because I am already implementing Serializable for my cooldowns class.

```
[21:16:29 WARN]: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.gmail.ketracoder.vts.Main

[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputS
tream.java:1184)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectO
utputStream.java:1548)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutp
utStream.java:1509)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Object
OutputStream.java:1432)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputS
tream.java:1178)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectO
utputStream.java:1548)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutp
utStream.java:1509)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Object
OutputStream.java:1432)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputS
tream.java:1178)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputSt
ream.java:348)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1
776)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native M
ethod)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMet
hodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Deleg
atingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStr
eamClass.java:988)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutp
utStream.java:1496)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Object
OutputStream.java:1432)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputS
tream.java:1178)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputSt
ream.java:348)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at com.gmail.ketracoder.vts.Shop.ActionHandler.disInit(A
ctionHandler.java:39)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at com.gmail.ketracoder.vts.Main.onDisable(Main.java:165
)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlug
in.java:323)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.disablePlugin
(JavaPluginLoader.java:359)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(S
implePluginManager.java:424)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugins(
SimplePluginManager.java:417)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R1.CraftServer.disablePlu
gins(CraftServer.java:334)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.stop(Min
ecraftServer.java:430)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R1.MinecraftServer.run(Mine
craftServer.java:561)
[21:16:29 WARN]:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The only time I put something in the HashMap, is when I call:

```
private void setCooldown(Player player, int slot, Main main, Shop shop){
        String playerName = player.getName();
        Cooldown cooldown = new Cooldown(playerName, shop);
        cooldowns.put(cooldown, System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

Comment: There appears to be a problem in your stack trace. Can you try recopying?

Comment: Recopied as it is from console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `Cooldown` class is what is causing the problem

No, the `Main` class is what is causing the problem, as the exception says:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.gmail.ketracoder.vts.Main
```

Clearly `Cooldown` is an inner class of `Main`, so it retains a reference to the enclosing object, which isn't serializable. Make it a static class, or an outer class.

NB calling `createNewFile()` in the place where you call it will yield a zero length file. You don't need to do that anywhere: `new FileOutputStream(...)` already does that. Just remove it.

Comment: Cooldown is a separate class, I'm not sure if it's causing the error.

Comment: @NeilDerno Either the code is not as you have represented here or it is causing this error by being an inner class. Possibly `Cooldown` has an *explicit*, non-static non-transient reference to `Main`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, I've checked the code. I've posted a better more detailed stack trace.

Comment: @NeilDerno Something somewhere is an inner class of, or has an explicit reference to,  `Main`. The stack trace says so. Is it `Shop`?

Comment: You, sir, are a true hero. + 1 for making the inner class static

Answer (score 1):

If you look for a non-`java.io` related method, starting from the deepest stacktrace entry, you will find `java.util.HashMap.writeObject` which is responsible for storing the objects *contained* in the `Map`. If a non-`Serializable` object like `com.gmail.ketracoder.vts.Main` is encountered during this process, it’s clear that you must have put it into the map before your attempt to serialize it, either as a key or a value (well, or both).

If you want to serialize a map, all objects contained in the map must be `Serializable`. Unlike, e.g. listeners on AWT components, there is no skipping of non-`Serializable` objects.

But note that what you are doing is dangerous. If an instance of `Main` is contained in the map while `Main` will, in turn, have a reference to the map (I guess that from the class name), you have a cyclic reference. While Serialization works in principle with cyclic object graphs, it will be very fragile when these are combined with `HashMap`s. The `HashMap` needs to rehash all elements when restoring the map, which may cause `hashCode` and `equals` invoked on incomplete objects in the case of cyclic object graphs.

Comment: The only time when I ever put something in the hashmap is when I call: http://pastebin.com/cmYPAcZA

Also, I've updated the StackTrace for future reference (i've ran it with a JDK instead of a JRE).

Comment: Whatever you say. stacktraces don’t lie; if it’s not contained directly, it’s referred by your `Cooldown` instance as EJP already said. If not directly, well, it’s the `Shop` instance that has a reference to `Main`.

Comment: I've never heard of the problem described in your last sentence. What's your source? And what do you mean by 'incomplete object'?

Comment: @EJP: suppose you are restoring a `Main` instance. It contains a reference to a `HashMap`, so this `HashMap` will be restored. This `HashMap` contains a reference to the `Main` instance, so it will be a back-reference to an instance previously seen in the stream. But at this time, the `Main` instance is still being under construction and may miss properties required for correct hash code calculation. I know the problem from personal experience and I guess, there are related questions here; the first found: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10031833/2711488 http://stackoverflow.com/q/7901006/2711488